# How to get the smallest next or previous possible double value supported by the architecture?

Tags: java, floating-point

Lets say I have a `double` variable `d`. Is there a way to get the next or previous value that is supported by the CPU architecture.

As a trivial example, if the value was 10.1245125 and the precision of the architecture was fixed to 7 decimal places, then the next value would be 10.1245126 and the previous value would be 10.1245124.

Obviously on floating-point architectures this is not that simple. How would I be able to achieve this (in Java)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Actually, an IEEE 754 floating-point architecture makes this easy: thanks to the standard, the function is called [nextafter](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_nextafter_double.htm) in nearly all languages that support it, and this uniformity allowed me to write an answer to your question with very little familiarity with Java:

> The `java.lang.Math.nextAfter(double start, double direction)` returns the floating-point number adjacent to the first argument in the direction of the second argument.

Remember that -infinity and +infinity are floating-point values, and these values are convenient to give the direction (second argument). Do not make the common mistake of writing something like `Math.nextAfter(x, x+1)`, which only works as long as 1 is greater than the [ULP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) of `x`.

Anyone who writes the above probably means instead `Math.nextAfter(x, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY)`, which saves an addition and works for all values of `x`.

Comment: Oh I missed that function! Thanks so much!

Comment: For more convenience see also [Math.nextUp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextUp-double-) and [Math.nextDown](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextDown-double-).

Comment: @BjörnZurmaar I am putting this into an answer because I lost a lot of additional time while looking exactly for those methods, I am citing you there but if you prefer to write your answer I will delete mine and upvote yours!

Answer (score 3):

[Math.nextUp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextUp-double-) and [Math.nextDown](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextDown-double-) can be used to get the next/previous element, which are equivalent to the proposed methods in the accepted answer, but more concise.

(this info has been originally provided as a comment by @BjörnZurmaar)

Comment: Nice alternative suggestion.